# Using Codecept and Puppeteer to test a div with role="combobox"

Tags: javascript, combobox, puppeteer

I am using Codecept and Puppeteer to submit a form with a Div that is using `role="combobox"`.
I can set the value of the combox box using:

```js
I.fillField('citizenships[0]', 'United States');
```

But the option also needs to be selected in order for the form to be populated.
The text field looks like this:

```html
<input 
  aria-invalid="true" 
  autocomplete="off" 
  name="citizenships[0]" 
  type="text" 
  class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input 
  MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput- 
  inputAdornedEnd" 
  aria-autocomplete="list" 
  autocapitalize="none" 
  spellcheck="false" 
  value="" 
  id="mui-autocomplete-16990" 
  aria-describedby="mui-autocomplete-16990-helper-text"
/>
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information. I am relatively new to automated testing. I can process a plain select element just fine but I am having a difficult time finding an example of populating a combobox that is constructed of an outer div and a list of text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the following code after setting the value of the field.
`I.pressKey('ArrowDown');`
`I.pressKey('Enter');`